# vector of pair of set with lambda comparator

Tags: c++, vector, set

I'm trying to make a vector of pairs of set: `vector<pair<set<int>, set<int>>>` but I want to use different lambda comparators for the two sets. 
I tried doing:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto cmp = [&] (int a, int b) -> bool {
        return a > b;
    };
    auto hi = [&] (int a, int b) -> bool {
        return a < b;
    };
    vector<pair<set<int, decltype(cmp)>, set<int, decltype(hi)>>> lol(cmp, hi);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gave me this error:

```
test.cpp:11:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<std::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> >, std::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >::vector(main()::<lambda(int, int)>&, main()::<lambda(int, int)>&)’
 ype(cmp)>, set<int, decltype(hi)>>> lol(cmp, hi);
                                                ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Also, is there any way to initialize the size of the vector as well?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass your lambdas to the constructor of the outer `vector`, which has no constructors that take lambdas as input.

You need to pass the lambdas to the `std::set` constructor instead, which means you need to construct the individual `std::set` instances (see [C++11 std::set lambda comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896032/)) and then push them into the vector, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

auto cmp = [] (int a, int b) -> bool {
    return a > b;
};

auto hi = [] (int a, int b) -> bool {
    return a < b;
};

using set_cmp = set<int, decltype(cmp)>;
using set_hi = set<int, decltype(hi)>;
using set_pair = pair<set_cmp, set_hi>;

int main()
{
    vector<set_pair> lol;
    ...
    lol.push_back(make_pair(set_cmp(cmp), set_hi(hi)));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

This means you would not be able to pre-size the vector, since it would need to be able to default-construct the `set` objects, thus you couldn't pass your lambdas to them.  If you want that, use stateless functors instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct cmp {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a > b;
    }
};

struct hi {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a < b;
    }
};

using set_cmp = set<int, cmp>;
using set_hi = set<int, hi>;
using set_pair = pair<set_cmp, set_hi>;

int main()
{
    vector<set_pair> lol(...desired size...);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```