# how to add lambda function or perform custom operation in STL set in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, set, declaration

I need a set arranges the value in such a way that if the int values are different i need the lexographically greater string to come front else i want the smaller integer to come front

```
set<pair<int,string>,[&](auto &a,auto &b){
    if(a.first==b.first)return a.second>b.second;
    return a.first<b.first;
}>;
```

Comment: Do you mean "if the int values are equal  i need the lexographically greater string to come front"?

Comment: i am talking about the 3rd question that came in leetcode contest today i hope u remember.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 std::set lambda comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896032/c11-stdset-lambda-comparison-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>


int main()
{
    auto less = []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 )
    {
        return std::tie( p1.first, p2.second ) < 
               std::tie( p2.first, p1.second );
    };
    std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>, decltype( less )> 
    s( { { 1, "A" }, { 1, "B" }, { 2, "A" } }, less );

    for ( const auto &p : s )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
1 B
1 A
2 A
```

You could use also the constructor without the initializer list

```
    std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>, decltype( less )> 
    s( less );
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad anyways i am a big Fan of your post's on Leetcode... Its an honor for me that u replied... :)

Comment: can u please tell me why u added std and tie?

Comment: @CodeforcesFan Using of the using directive is not a good idea. It is better to use qualified names. std::tie allows to simplify the condition without using if-else.

Comment: okk... thanks vlad   :)