# How to refer to the enclosing class member variables from inside of a nested class instance?

Tags: c++, stdset

As a class member of some class `A`, I would like to maintain an `std::set` storing `B`s. The set uses a custom comparison object which needs to read a non-static class member, `m_t` in the example code below, to perform its comparison.

Example code:

```cpp
class B { ... };

class A {
    struct Comp {
        bool operator()(B b1, B b2) const {
            // ... compares b1 and b2, uses m_t
        }
    };
    std::set<B, Comp> m_set;
    double m_t;
};
```

Unfortunately this does not compile as understandably we cannot access a non-static member of `A` within `Comp`. Is there some other way to achieve this? I would like to avoid making `m_t` static.

(Some background for context: this is for implementing a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). Specifically, `B` implements a function dependent on `m_t`, where `m_t` varies between 0 and 1. The functions do not intersect within [0, 1], so the comparisons between `B`s never change, thus keeping the `std::set` valid. With the sweepline at a given `m_t`, I then need to query with a given value which functions in the set surround it.)

**Edit:** I had already seen the question this is now marked as a duplicate to, [Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator). The answers there do explain how to make a custom comparator, but have nothing to do with referring to another class member.

Comment: The comparator will have to have m_factor inside it, won't it?

Comment: Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896032/c11-stdset-lambda-comparison-function

Comment: I do not understand... "so the comparisons between Bs never change" then why do you need `m_t` for the comparison if it has no impact?

Comment: IMO the duplicate doesn't answer the question. OP is apparently aware of how to make the custom comparator, the question is rather how to refer to the enclosing class instance from inside of a nested class instance

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because while it indeed does not impact comparisons _between_ `B`s, it does impact the query. The comparisons with the query value should be done for that specific `m_t`.

Comment: *Does that make sense?* not quite. A set is ordered by using the comparator, you cannot later use eg `set::find` with a different comparator. Maybe I just don't understand what you mean with "query"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Imagine that I insert two functions `y = t` and `y = t + 1` into the set. Then if I set `m_t = 0` and use `std::find` with `y = 1`, I will get `y = t + 1`. If I then set `m_t = 1` and use `std::find` with `y = 1`, I will get `y = t`.

Comment: `std::set::find` does not work like that. If you mean `std::find` then you can use whatever comparator you like. It does not have to be the one you used for sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Comp` is just a C++ class, so you can complement it with any data as needed. E.g. a pointer to the enclosing class instance:

```
struct A {
    
    struct Comp {
        A *host;
        
        bool operator()(B b1, B b2) const {
            std::cout << host->m_t << std::endl;
            // ...m_t is accessible here
        }
    };
    
    double m_t;
    std::set<B, Comp> m_set{ Comp { this } };
    
};
```